# How implement AMP Stories as alternative to a existing site

Tags: amp-html, amp-stories

I have a site as Html and amp-html.
Now I want to start convert the amp-html site as an alternative site as a story.

The question is now how to handle the canonical tag.
My idea is add two canonical tags to html version. One for each version.
And of course the canonaical tag to each htm-amp version.

But I'am not sure it is the right handling to use two canonical to diferend AMP sites. So my Question:

How can I setup AMP-stories as an alternative to an existing AMP site? I don't want drop the existing html-amp site.

Comment: The format is intended to represent a single piece of content, and would likely be a poor experience for representing an entire website.  Are you intending to create multiple stories (one for each page of your site)?

Comment: yes for evry site a own story to the topic. And link from html and AMP to the story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [`amp-story` documentation](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-story/amp-story.md#required-markup-for-amp-story), stories are expected to be self-canonical (that is, the `href` of the `<link rel="canonical">` tag should point to the story itself).  It is also not valid AMP to have more than one canonical link per document.